# How to force scroll position to top at page refresh (html)?

Tags: scroll

I would like to force the scroll position to go to top everytime i refresh, is that possible? If yes could you help me to do that step by step? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After the page is loaded (aka. inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); ), insert in your JS:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```